# Unity Game View support Touch Events?

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

I would like to buy me a Microsoft Surfacebook. But bevore I would like to know if Unity IDE support Touch Events in the Game View of the Editor? Or only if a real device is connect? But the monitor itselft is a touch device.

Thanks for help!
Regards,
Markus

Answer (score 1):

Few days, there was a similar question about touch detection in Unity using Windows tablets.

There is no support for the touch. `Input.touches` and `Input.GetTouch` will **not** work in the Editor Game View. It will only work when you deploy the Game.

For some [reason](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/surface-pro-3-unity.286775/#post-1893986), touches are treated as mouse input.
This shouldn't be a problem at-all because `Input.mousePosition` and `OnMouseDown` will work on it so you can use pre-processor to detect when in Editor mode then use `input.mousePosition` and `OnMouseDown` and then be able to test your app without having to build it.

Everything else should be fine. Remember, it is not a real computer. It is a mobile computer and is weaker than a real computer. Don't expect a 4K texture game to run smoothly on this device.